# I need innerHTML with the library PHP Simple DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom

I have been working on **PHP Simple DOM Parser** and the issue i am facing now is i cannot get **innerHTML** with the library. Need Help
Library link:
`http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/`
If you had used this library you can help me finding either this library supports/generates inner-HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution trying its function.
you can get html by using innertext() or outertext() functions

```
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');
$html->innertext;
```